# How to check if 2 different breeds of turtles are on the same patch

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

The final part of my design involves me recording down anytime a car breed drives into or in netlogo terms, is on the same patch or X and Y coordinate as the people breed as they navigate across the edge of the screen. Had this been java I could've done something like

if Car.xPostion == Person.xPostion

(Do something...)

But unfortunately I do not know how to do the same in NetLogo, all I've been able to do so far is just ask the two breeds by giving every turtle a boolean variable called movable and setting them to true and the rest to false, is there anyway I can check the two coordinates of two different turtles on Netlogo? This is all I 've been able to do so far.

```
to record-accidents

  ask turtles with [movable? = true]

  [

  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tried something like your java approach, it would fail because turtle positions are continuous and floating numbers are nearly always not equal.

If I have understood your question correctly, you have given a boolean variable called movable? set to true for cars and false for all other breeds. You don't need to do this, turtles know their own breed so you can do `ask cars`.

To answer your specific question, there are several ways to approach it depending on the perspective (sort of, which agent is in charge).

You could identify patches where there are accidents:, which is the answer to your question in the title (about identifying patches with two breeds).

```
let accident-locations patches with [any? people-here and any? cars-here]
if any? accident-locations
[ ask accident-locations
  [ <do something>
```

But you can also take a turtle perspective. You could start from pedestrians who have been hit. This takes advantage of the fact that turtles can automatically access the patch variables (like `turtles-here`) for the patch where they are located:

```
let hit people with [any? cars-here]
if any? hit
[ ask hit...
```

or from cars:

```
let hitters cars with [any? people-here]
if any? hitters
[ ask hitters...
```

Comment: so you don't want to identify these patches, just count them? Then something like `set num-accidents num-accidents + count patches with [any? people-here and any? cars-here]` with num-accidents as a global variable

Comment: Number of accidents this tick is `count patches with [any? people-here and any? cars-here]`. If you want the total over time, just have the monitor display the global variable that you are increasing. Otherwise, needs a new question so you can explain more fully the problem,